# Usage of "suppose"?

Tags: grammar

What is correct/wrong?

So far we supposed that it is on you to check whether to send dunning letters
by E-Mail or by mail.

or:

So far we've supposed that it is on you to check whether to send dunning letters
by e-mail or by mail.

or a better sentence?

Comment: Probably better to use "assumed", since it's meaning is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is better but not perfect. I would suggest that you use *assumed* instead of *supposed*.

If this is part of a letter or communication that is even slightly formal (and in the context of  dunning letters it is probably safe to assume this) it is better to use *we have* instead of *we've*. Also, *it is on you* is an informal, if not quite slang, way of saying *it is your responsibility*.

I would suggest rewriting the sentence as follows:

*So far we have assumed that it is your responsibility to check whether to send dunning letters by e-mail or by mail.*